# SQL Query subquery with COUNT()

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, count, ssms

I'm trying to return the 'conm' that has 79 rows only.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT *
FROM combinedata1 
WHERE EXISTS (    
    SELECT conm, COUNT(conm) AS 'Number of Rows'
    FROM combinedata1 
    GROUP BY conm
    HAVING COUNT(conm) = 79
)
ORDER BY conm ASC
```

Apparently, this is returning almost everything, ignoring the `conm` with 79 rows.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Thanks.

Comment: The subquery will do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have `where` inside `exists` as following

```
SELECT *
FROM combinedata1 c1
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT c2.conm, COUNT(c2.conm) AS 'Number of Rows'
    FROM combinedata1 c2
    WHERE c1.conm = c2.conm
    GROUP BY c2.conm
    HAVING COUNT(c2.conm) = 79
)
ORDER BY conm ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

I find that it is simpler to express with a scalar subquery than with `exists`:

```
select c.*
from combinedata1 c
where (select count(*) from combinedata1 where c1.conm = c.conm) = 79
```

The subquery just count how many rows with the same `conm` can be found in the table: this returns a scalar value (the count), which you can directly filter on. This query would take advantage of an index on `conm`.

You could also use window functions:

```
select *
from (select c.*, count(*) over(partition by conm) cnt from combinedata1 c) c
where cnt = 79
```

Answer (score 0):

First, your query is returning everything because that is how `EXISTS` work.  The subquery is not related to the outer query.  So, either all rows are returned (if the subquery returns any rows) or no rows are returned.

You can fix this with a correlated subquery.  However window functions are faster and simpler to query:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM (SELECT c.*, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY conm) as cnt
      FROM combinedata1 c
     ) c
WHERE cnt = 79;
ORDER BY conm ASC;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT conm, COUNT(conm) AS 'Number_of_Rows'
FROM combinedata1 
GROUP BY conm
)
WHERE Number_of_Rows = 79;
```

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.